# Tomcat 8 doesn't start

Tags: centos, java, tomcat

Upgraded tomcat 6 to 8 on Centos 7.

I get this error in logs:
`/usr/local/ctera/apache-tomcat-8.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: line 421: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/ctera/apache-tomcat-8.0.14/endorsed: No such file or directory`

This is the only entry in logs...

This directory didn't exist, so I created it, with permission 777.
Still get same error.

Tomcat 6 did not produce such an error.

I read a little about the endorsed directory - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html
and it shouldn't be a critical issue, but it is.
What should I do..?

Answer (score 0):

[RUNNING.txt](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) provides a description of the `endorsed` directory:

> Libraries that override standard "[Endorsed Standards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/index.html)" libraries
>   provided by JRE. See [Classloading documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#XML_Parsers_and_Java) in the User Guide for
>   details. By default this "endorsed" directory is absent.

It should be safe to ignore, though I suspect JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS is defined somewhere to point to that PATH. Is that a relative PATH to your installation?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between tomcat 6 and tomcat 8 catalina.sh java process initiation.

In my case the problem was NOT in the endorsed directory, but in setting a different parameter before the endorsed dir, that included spaces, adding `\` before them solved the problem.